# The cluster initialization sequence is faulty in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

#### Describe the bug

The cluster initialization sequence is faulty.
version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 6c757da5e31800c4c802bd2cc2f5877b9d392ae7
cnosdb 2.3.3, revision 6df6a1ffca50d6a22105930bff518d0bc5d6c0cb
mode:3meta + 2 (query+tskv)

#### To Reproduce

```bash
bash run_cluster.sh
```

check the log:

```
ERROR meta::model::meta_admin: Failed to get disk info '/tmp/cnosdb/1001/db': No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

If a database is created after the cluster is pulled up, an error message may be displayed as follows

```
public ❯ create database benchmark with shard 2;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030053","error_message":"Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 0"}
public ❯ create database benchmark with shard 2;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030053","error_message":"Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 0"}
public ❯ create database benchmark with shard 2;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030053","error_message":"Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 0"}
public ❯ create database benchmark with shard 2;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030053","error_message":"Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 0"}
public ❯ create database benchmark with shard 2;
```

#### Expected behavior

*No response*

#### Additional context

*No response*

Comment: Copied and pasted directly from the issue?